# Creating a VWAP for 24 hour trading that resets itself

Tags: pine-script

I trade the ES which is a 24 hour market.

I've noticed that the standard VWAP doesnt quite work as efficiently due to the nature of 24 hour trading.

So I'm trying to create a new VWAP which resets after every session.  So it has a VWAP for normal business hours (09:30 - 16:00) and then resets and calculates a new VWAP between 16:00-09:30.

I have code to distinguish between the business day and the overnight market:

```
t = time(period, "0930-1600")
mkt_hours = na(t) ? na : 1
```

And here is the code to calculate VWAP for a certain number of periods:

```
cumulativePeriod = input(14, "Period")
typicalPrice = (high + low + close) / 3
typicalPriceVolume = typicalPrice * volume
cumulativeTypicalPriceVolume = sum(typicalPriceVolume, cumulativePeriod)
cumulativeVolume = sum(volume, cumulativePeriod)
vwapValue = cumulativeTypicalPriceVolume / cumulativeVolume
plot(vwapValue)
```

But I cant figure out how to reset the VWAP at 09:30 and 16:00 every day.

Any ideas?

Cheers

Answer (score 1):

I am looking for something similar to allow for an anchored VWAP.  I have been able to work this out by manually specifying the bar number to anchor the VWAP too but havnt had any luck returning the barnumber of a specific time or condition.  ie.  ideally i want to run a VWAP from a session low or session high.

below is the code from Jayy's tradingview study for anchoring vwap by defined time or bar number.

```
startBar01=input(0,"1/ Starting Bar Number, for Midas VWAP", 
integer,minval=-1)
up01=input(false, title="Show upper resistance only - top to trend down" )
mid01=input(true, title=" Show MIDAS line (midline)")
low01=input(false, title="Show lower support only - bottom to trend up" )

v01 = na(volume) ? 1 : volume
cumV01= cum(v01)
CumPV01= cum(hl2*v01)
SupportCumPV01 = cum(low*v01)
ResistanceCumPV01 = cum(high*v01)

startV01 = valuewhen(startmidas01,cumV01,0)
StartPV01 = valuewhen(startmidas01,CumPV01,0)
SupportStartPV01 = valuewhen(startmidas01,SupportCumPV01,0)
ResistanceStartPV01 = valuewhen(startmidas01,ResistanceCumPV01,0)

Midas01 = (CumPV01-StartPV01)/(cumV01-startV01)
SupportMidas01 = (SupportCumPV01-SupportStartPV01)/(cumV01-startV01)
ResistanceMidas01 = (ResistanceCumPV01-ResistanceStartPV01)/(cumV01-startV01)

middle01 = plot( mid01 and showmidas? Midas01:na, color=aqua,linewidth=3, title="Midas Resistance 1M")
lower01 = plot(low01 and showmidas? SupportMidas01:na, color=teal,linewidth=1, title="Midas Resistance 1S")
upper01 = plot(up01 and showmidas?ResistanceMidas01:na, color=RED,linewidth=1, title="Midas Resistance 1R")
fill(lower01,upper01,color=#1c86ee,transp=97)
```